# Provisioning an Azure VM agent using a Jenkins Multipipeline

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins instance running on an AWS EC2. Rather than use the built-in nodes(i have disabled them), I need to provision an Azure VM agent, perform builds and execute tests on that agent. Using the https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-vm-agents/ via a freestyle job I was able to successfully provision an Azure VM agent on demand. However I an unable to achieve the same via a Multibranch pipeline ( there is a seperate repo for Jenkins File and one for the code repo) (plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/remote-file/). It does not seem to kick of the Azure VM agent and fails waiting for an agent. If i enable the built-in node, it works. So it appears that via the pipeline the azure-vm-agents is not triggering for provisioning. . There appears as if a link `For how to select agent in pipeline, refer to this doc.` within the https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-vm-agents/  page does not lead anywhere. Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: May I ask the reason for cross-cloud platform agent usage?

Comment: Sure. The reason is constraints wrt client and other suppliers. Also as mentioned the freestyle job provisions an azure vm agent.